# Índice Full Text para Banco de dados voltado para Ecommerce!

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, query, índices

Li várias postagens aqui no SOPT sobre criação de `índices` a qual me tirou inúmeras duvidas que tinha, mas a minha principal é sobre `FULL TEXT`!

Em um banco de dados que é exclusivamente voltado para `ecommerce`, onde existem `inserts`, `updates` e `deletes` o tempo todo. Eu tenho que frequentemente estar recriando estes índices ou `mysql` faz isso automaticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O MySQL não recria os índices FULLTEXT automaticamente.**

Deleções de registros que possuem colunas com índice deste tipo são gravadas em tabelas auxiliares, utilizadas como filtro para retornar os resultados das consultas sem as deleções. Como **vantagem**, as deleções são rápidas e performáticas. Porém, a **desvantagem** é que o tamanho do índice não é imediatamente reduzido após a deleção dos registros. Para remover as entradas de índices FULLTEXT e melhorar a performance das consultas, é necessário fazer o rebuild do índice, conforme instruções abaixo.

Para recriar um índice FULLTEXT você precisa habilitar `innodb_optimize_fulltext_only` e rodar `OPTIMIZE TABLE`:

```
mysql> set GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=ON;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> OPTIMIZE TABLE opening_lines;
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Table              | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
| test.opening_lines | optimize | status   | OK       |
+--------------------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Maiores detalhes podem ser vistos na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html).